# INVALID_CONTENT_HASH error using Bittex API v3

Tags: node.js, authentication

I'm using Bittrex API v3. My header setup as below:

```
body = {
 "marketSymbol":"BTC-USD",
 "direction":"SELL",
 "type":"LIMIT",
 "quantity":"0.6",
 "limit":"6000",
 "timeInForce":"IMMEDIATE_OR_CANCEL"
}
var contentHash = CryptoJS.SHA512(JSON.stringify(body)).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex)
```

But I get INVALID_CONTENT_HASH. 
If anyone can solve this problem, please let me know as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

The v3 API is expecting the content to be hashed as json (which you're doing) but the payload must also be POSTed as json with the `Content-Type` accordingly set to `application/json`.

I ran into the same problem with the json being converted to a querystring on POST.